# how to write the sparql Describe result on a txt file

Tags: java, sparql, jena

I am new in sementic web. I am trying to write the results of the SPARQL describe query on file. I am getting one line again and again. can someone help me to solve this.

If select is the best option to use then please advise me according.

```
    public void getResourceDescription(String rname){

    String desptstring ="Prefix dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>\n" +
            "Describe ?r  where{" +
            "    <"+rname+"> ?r ?o." +
            "}";

    Writer writer = null;
    Query des_query = QueryFactory.create(desptstring);
    QueryExecution des_Exe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql", des_query);

    try {
        Model model = des_Exe.execDescribe();
        //model = (Model) set;
        //ResultSet description_result = des_Exe.execSelect();

        StringWriter strwrt = new StringWriter();
        //for ( ; description_result.hasNext() ; ) {
        //QuerySolution res = description_result.nextSolution();

        Abbreviated abb = new Abbreviated();
        abb.write(model, strwrt, null);
        //System.out.println(res);

        File file = new File("D:\\newfile.txt");
        file.createNewFile();
        Files.write(Paths.get("D:\\newfile.txt"), strwrt.toString().getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        // }

    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        des_Exe.close();
    }




} // ending of the GetResourceDescription Method
```

Comment: it should be `model.write(...)` - and the file name shouldn't be called `.txt` given that the content is RDF...depending on the serialization format (RDF/XML, N-Triples, ...) you should use the recommended file extension. E.g. for N-Triples it's `.nt`

Comment: By the way, [documentation](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/rdf-output.html) explains everything perfectly.